# Align TabLayout titles left and right

Tags: android

I am working on a little dictionary app which currently looks like this:

[image]

I want the start of the first tab title and the end of the last tab title to be aligned with the start of péngyou and the end of HSK 1.

I tried using custom layouts for the first and last tab aligning the text left and right and using the correct padding, but that leaves me with two problems.

1. The distribution of the tab titles looks off. I guess tabs originally have equal width and the titles are centered in their respective tab. Do I have to calculate the positioning for the remaining tab titles myself? How could I achieve that
2. I use tabIndicatorFullWidth="false", but the tab indicator gets centered in the tab instead of being aligned with the title. Do I have to overwrite the tab indicator behavior? If yes, where would I do that and how could I achieve alignment regardless of where the title is aligned in the tab?

Did I miss an easy solution to this problem?

Comment: set tabMode="scrollable" and check it once

Comment: @NensiKasundra That makes all tabs gather on the left

Comment: What you want exactly

Comment: No, I also want the end of WORDS to be aligned with the end of HSK 1

Comment: tabMode="fixed" have you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by using tabMode="scrollable" and a custom TabLayout. In the onMeasure function of the TabLayout I calculatted the width each tab should have and added paddings accordingly.